# How to achieve 'A' ranking on forgotten forest in Kameo Elements of Power

Tags: achievements, rare-replay, kameo-elements-of-power

So I absolutely love Kameo, however, out of all my years of playing the game I have never figured out a way to achieve an A ranking on the Forgotten Forest. What score needs to be achieved in order to get an A on this level and what would be the best way to go about achieving such a score?

Answer (score -1):

To achieve an A rank on Forgotten Forest you need at least 15,000,000 points ([source](https://www.xboxachievements.com/game/kameo-elements-of-power/achievement/1351-Forgotten-Forest-ranking.html)). There is a guide on YouTube on how to achieve an A rank :

- [Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMviFGJvrI0)
- [Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jO9vCEtR7g)
- [Part 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7Yw1X_j7G4)